# Is there any event in magento which i call after successful invoice creation

Tags: php, magento, events

I am providing connectivity with a accounting s/w , so I am calling one event `"sales_order_invoice_pay"` but I need to update the invoice no. by the invoice no. provided by accounting s/w. So I need a event in which I can get the information of invoice just after invoice generation.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends on your magento version also because earlier magento has

```
sales_order_invoice_save_after
```

But you have to check your version and availability of the event.